# What is the recommended PHP version for froala editor?

Tags: php, froala

Uploading & display an image in froala editor works, but I have a free account at 000webhost.com. And can't seem to find the recommeded PHP version for froala editor. My PHP version on my machine is 5.5.44. And PHP version of 000webhost is 5.2

Thanx in advance...

Comment: Forgot to mention. Uploading an image works in 000webhost but don't get a respone. In dev tools I see the POST in network tab but no GET for the image. It works well on my localhost on my machine

Answer (score 0):

Frola editor is jquery plugin and it works with javscript so PHP is not used.

Comment: Yes but what about the server integration? It comes with a "upload_image.php" file

Comment: upload_image.php is just example, you are can edit and adjust this script to your needs.